# Why are numbers with a leading sign (plus or minus) when converted to BigDecimal, treated as valid numbers in Java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

The following expressions are valid in Java as obvious

```
int a = -0;
int b = +0;
```

and so are the following.

```
Integer c = new Integer(-0);
int d = Integer.parseInt("-0");
BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal("-0");
```

---

The following statements are however invalid.

```
Integer f = new Integer("+0");   //Leading + sign.
int g=Integer.parseInt("+0");    //Leading + sign.
```

Both of them throw the `NumberFormatException`.

The following statement with `BigDecimal` however compiles and runs without causing an exception to be thrown.

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("+0");  //Leading + sign.
```

Why is a leading `+` sign valid with `BigDecimal` here which however doesn't appear to be the case with the other datatypes available in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), negative signs needs the minus sign. But if its a positive Integer, no need for a plus sign.

`public static int parseInt(String s)`

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, **except that
>   the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to
>   indicate a negative value**. The resulting integer value is returned,
>   exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to
>   the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

Then for the constructor:

`public Integer(String s)`

> The string is converted to an int value in **exactly the manner used by the parseInt method** for radix 10.

Comment: As to why the leading pluses are not supported, [from Joshua Bloch](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=6ac6ab4d919c450875cf1888ef9?bug_id=4296955):
"... There is code inside the Java platform libraries that would break if we were to change Integer.parseInt's behavior to allow for a leading plus sign (e.g., BigInteger's String constructor), and it is quite likely that we are not unique in this regard.  I strongly suspect that our customers also have code that would break if we were to make the suggested incompatible specification change at this late date."

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is *most likely* that the inconsistent behaviour between `new Integer("+0")` and `new BigDecimal("+0")` is a result of a mistake in design of one or the other.  Unfortunately, the mistake got "baked on" when the relevant class was publicly released, and Sun / Oracle were unwilling to fix it because:

1. the respective implementations do conform to their respective specifications,
2. the inconsistency is a relatively minor issue with a simple work-around, and
3. fixing it is likely to break forwards and backwards compatibility.

(And this explanation is supported by the evaluation section of [Java Bug #4296955](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4296955) that @rlay3 found!!)

---

Note that I have excluded your Java expression examples from consideration.  That is because the context for Java expression syntax and converting text strings are sufficiently different that (IMO) you should not *expect* them to behave the same.  (And in the same way, you should not expect a String reader to do something special with any `\` characters that it encounters ...)

---

**UPDATE**

@ADTC has observed that they actually did change this in Java 7 and that `Integer.parseInt` now *does* accept a leading `+` sign.

The corresponding Java bug for this enhancement is [#5017980](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5017980).  (And if you look at the linked bugs, the first one *seems* to imply that the change has been backported to OpenJDK6.)

However, Oracle *didn't* mention this change in the Java 7 compatibility / upgrade documents ... which is strange given that Sun had previously rejected the change *because of compatibility concerns!!*

This is all rather peculiar ...

Comment: Stephen C:) It appears to be deliberate according to the specification. Doesn't it?

Comment: It is not obvious whether the specification or the implementation came first ... or whether the original decision was made with due  consideration, or whether it happened by default.  "Deliberate" and "mistake" are not contradictory.  Deliberate actions are often judged to be mistakes in hindsight.

Comment: This actually changed in *Java 7* and [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) now accepts the positive sign.